# how to become @media's first rank?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, media

I created a navbar.  It hides if you scroll down and appears if you scroll up. I solved it with JavaScript but I have a problem.

I scroll down and scroll up after when I squeeze the window, the logo does not diminish.  I created a @media where I set the logo height from 170px to 120px.  I write everything in a css file but when I modify an element style with Javascript this happen:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As [static_null](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8849764/static-null) correctly pointed out, you could change your media query to

```
@media only screen and (max-width:1300px){
   #cimpic{
      height: 120px !important;
   }
}
```

or you could remove the inline style for the height of #cimpic and move it to your stylesheet. That would make it easier to manipulate based on the viewport, ie

```
#cimpic{
  height: 120px;
}  

@media only screen and (min-width:1300px){
   #cimpic{
      height: 170px;
   }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: in the default situation the #cimpic height style doesn't there inline. When I scroll down and scroll up, it at the time go there :/ I'm sorry but my English skill is low :(

Comment: Hi @Akos, if I look at the web inspector screenshot you posted, it shows style=" height:170px;". Do you know where this is coming from?

Comment: Thanks @Akos, that helps. As a quick experiment, you could try adding the second block of CSS above to your site, and in your javascript, comment out the 2 lines that set the height of #cimpic

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the media query is after the original code in the stylesheet. Alternatively, you can always throw an !important at the end of the the statement if you were really lazy, however, it is bad practice. I recommend reading into CSS specificity:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity